# SLIM REST | .htaccess return error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I'm trying to install SLIM Framework to the root.

My .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And when I'm tried to load http://mydomain.com I'm always getting 500 Error.

My index file:

```
...
$app->get("/", function () {
        echo "<h1>Hello Slim World</h1>";
    });
...
```

If I'm tried to rename my .htaccess -> it's working.
Where is my error?
Thanks.

Comment: A 500 error means "_go look in your Apache error log_" where you will find more details. If it is an Apache error in the .htaccess, you'll see it there. If it is a PHP error and error_reporting is enabled, you'll see that as well. Always use `display_errors` when developing PHP code (not in production) `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks. was trying to work out a broken htaccess config and could not figure it out.  Checking the apache log revealed: `bad flag delimiters` which I solved using this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890004/rewriterule-error-bad-flag-delimiters