# Internal Server Error .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, database, .htaccess, wamp

I have a problem with my `.htaccess` file.

In my `.htaccess` file I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) user.php?u=$1 [NC, L]
```

And it is placed in my `C:/../wamp/www/mysite/`

My site worked before I had this file, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I'm kind of new to this aswell so it's bound to go wrong.
Whenever I run my site I get the error:
Internal Server Error

"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: That's a syntax error. You didn't finish the rule.

Comment: @PraveenKumar , how do I finish it then?

Comment: I guess add a `$` before `user.php`. I have put it in an answer. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Can you see the error logs and tell what's happening?

Comment: Do you have access to Apache's Error Log?

Comment: @PraveenKumar , it says "Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

Comment: Try giving the `on` as `On`?

Comment: Nopes, that doesn't solve. Open a new file, using Notepad or basic text editor and type it. Don't paste it. Looks like a malformed `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Also see what happens if you remove the empty line?

Comment: Dude, did you enable the rewrite engine?

Comment: It says "RewriteEngine on"? How do you enable it?

Comment: **1.** Find the `httpd.conf` file (usually you will find it in a folder called conf, config or something along those lines)
**2.** Inside the `httpd.conf` file uncomment the line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` (remove the pound '`#`' sign from in front of the line)
**3.** Also find the line `ClearModuleList` is uncommented then find and make sure that the line `AddModule mod_rewrite.c` is not commented out.

Comment: You can use the `W` » Apache » Apache Modules » mod_rewrite, if you are using WAMPServer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar It can't find "Addmodule mod_rewrite.c" and" ClearModuleList" in the httpd.conf file

Comment: Did you try searching for `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`, just search for `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar , it only finds the LoadModule rewrite_module thing, not the rest

Comment: Okay, is there a `#` symbol before that line?

Comment: Man, check this na: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYACNC_RhF0

Comment: If you are struggling with this, there's a Youtube video on how to do it: [**Youtube: How to enable rewrite module in WAMP Server?**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYACNC_RhF0)

Comment: It is because of the space. Change your rewrite rule's flags to `[NC,L]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't finished the rule, change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
#-------------------------------^
```

Okay, now that it looks like you haven't enabled the rewrite engine. Check [.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m) for more information on how to enable it.

**Update:** If you are struggling with this, there's a Youtube video on how to do it: [**Youtube: How to enable rewrite module in WAMP Server?**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYACNC_RhF0)

**Update:** If you get **Bad Flag Delimiters** error, please don't give any spaces between the flags. For more information, see [RewriteRule Error: Bad flag delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890004/rewriterule-error-bad-flag-delimiters).

Comment: Ok, i did everything, but it says that "mysite/profile/user/xxx was not found on this server"

Comment: This is my .htaccess: "RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]"

Comment: @Denny123 Try `mysite/user/xxx`?

Comment: The initial part of the answer is incorrect. It is not a requirement to have `$` at the end of a regular expression. Most likely the `mod_rewrite` was not enabled.

Comment: @Rolice True. I checked. :)