# PHP Rewrite the URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the URL using `.htaccess`. These all the things I want to do with the rewriting

1. Remove the file extension from the URL
2. Pass the parameter through URL and GET it in the file

My current `.htaccess` the file is as below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ works?v=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite and remove the file extension (`http://example.com/file.php` to `http://example.com/file`)

I want to send some data (maybe a string) to the page

let's say `http://example.com/file2.php?v=something`

I want to rewrite it as `http://example.com/file2/something` and get the value in the file

I tried the following methods

[Method 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

[Method 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables)

If I try [Method 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) and [Method 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables) (one after another), it's throwing following error

> [Sat Aug 03 12:13:12.881757 2019] [core:alert] [pid 23832:tid 1912]
>   [client ::1:62842] path/to/htaccess/file/.htaccess:
>   RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

I tried [This Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890004/rewriterule-error-bad-flag-delimiters) to prevent that error then It threw me below error

> [Sat Aug 03 13:14:02.121514 2019] [core:error] [pid 23832:tid 1916]
>   (20023)The given path was above the root path: [client ::1:51899]
>   AH00127: Cannot map GET
>   /path/to/my/file2?v=something.php HTTP/1.1 to file

I think it because `.htaccess` is rewriting the value as `.php` file.

How can I hide file extension and Get the value at the same time?

Comment: The first error you get is not about the rule, but the flag you use in the end of the rule. Which flags you use?

Comment: At first, I used `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ works?v=$1 [NC,L]`, it was throwing the first error. so I changed it into `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ works?v=$1 [L,R=301,NC]` This try throw me the second error

Comment: Did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890004/rewriterule-error-bad-flag-delimiters

Comment: Yes, By checking this only I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php?v=$2 [END]
```

This certainly can be refined further for your specific case. You question is a bit vague in a few points. But above example should point you into the right direction...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

Comment: This is kinda working for me, Now its not showing 500 error. but Server is taking `file2/something` as folder though. all of my `CSS` and `JS` are taking that URL also. like this `path/to/file2/something/css/base.css` and im getting `GET path/to/file2/something/css/base.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` error in console. this should work only in `file2.php` and should not use the same for `CSS` and `JS` links.

Comment: A request to `/file2/something/css/base.css` will _not_ get rewritten by above rule. because the second capture in the second rule's condition does _not_ match if the section of the path following the first virtual folder contains a `/`. So I assume you did not really use the code above but some variant you altered.